# What's the preferred way in c to map some values to other values?

Tags: c

I'm a python programmer who is doing a project in c. I need to map letters to the usb sendcodes corresponding to them. In python I would hardcode in a dictionary. In C I'm using a giant `switch` statement. Is there a better way?

```
switch(c){
    case 'a':
        return "x04";
        break;
    case 'b':
        return "x05";
        break;
    case 'c':
        return "x06";
        break;
```

Comment: they are seuqnetial? x04,x05...x026

Comment: If all your keys are sequential like that, you could use an array and use `c - 'a'` as the index.

Comment: I would use an array indexed by the letters (shifted to 0 base of course..)

Comment: @FredLarson While `c - 'a'` will work with ASCII encoding, it's not mandated to work for any characters except digits by the C specification.

Comment: Why not a 256 entry look-up table? This could be as simple as `char[256]`.

Comment: Do you really want to map to a string? Then sprintf the c-'a'+4. But if you actually want to map to integer values it is directly c-'a'+4.

Comment: @tadmann The usual problem with `some_type lookup[256]` is that users tend to use it via `lookup[c]` rather than the correct `lookup[c - CHAR_MIN]` or some other scheme to cope with negative `char c`.

Comment: C compilers compile giant switch statements into a jump table, if the hardware architecture supports it. This means the giant switch statement is a good option in practice, especially if it is easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

For my part, I'd create a lookup table:

```
static char sendcodes[256][5]; // declared outside of any function;
                               // "static" means it's only visible
                               // within the current source file

void init_sendcodes( void )
{
  for ( unsigned char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++ )
    sprintf( sendcodes[c], "%02hhx", c - 'a' + 4 );
}

char *mapSendcode( char c )
{
  return sendcodes[c];
}
```

Note that this code assumes an encoding where `'a'` through `'z'` are contiguous (ASCII or UTF-8). If they're not, well, you'll have to use multiple loops.

When you're done, `sendcode['a']` contains the string `"0x04"`, `sendcode['b']` contains `"0x05"`, etc.  So while it takes some work to initialize the table, you only have to do that once at the beginning of the program - after that it's just an array lookup.

Comment: `sendcodes[c]` may be indexed with a negative `c`.  Suggest `sendcodes[(unsigned char) c];`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your system is using something like ASCII or UTF-8 character encoding, where the Latin letters a-z are sequential, you can create an array of your values:

```
char *sendcodes[] = { "0x04", "0x05", "0x06", ... };
```

Then you would index it by subtracting `'a'` from the letter in question, giving you an index from 0 to 25:

```
return sendcodes[c - 'a'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using parallel arrays, as long as you have the same amount of data in both of the arrays. Just loop through the first array and use the variable `i` as an index into the second array:

```
char array1[]  = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
char *array2[] = {"x04", "x05", "x06"};

for (int i=0; i<sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]); i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", array2[i]);
}
```

Comment: The first array isn't really being used here.  Even if it was, you'd need to search it instead of indexing it directly.